# get data of the user logged in to discord with next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js

How can I pull the banner, id, etc. of the logged in user? next@12 next-auth@4.24.6
When I log the profile part at the bottom, all the information comes out, but when I try to do it in the frontend part, I can't pull it in a way I don't understand. I just started next.js. I couldn't use next-auth with next.js version 14. :D

```
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: { params: { scope: "identify guilds" } },
      profile(profile) {
        if (profile.avatar === null) {
          const defaultAvatarNumber = parseInt(profile.discriminator) % 5;
          profile.image_url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/${defaultAvatarNumber}.png`;
        } else {
          const format = profile.avatar.startsWith("a_") ? "gif" : "png";
          profile.image_url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${profile.id}/${profile.avatar}.${format}`;
        }

        return {
          id: profile.id,
          name: profile.username,
          discriminator: profile.discriminator,
          image: profile.image_url,
          banner: profile.banner,
          accentColor: profile.accentColor,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      if (session) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
        session.tokenType = token.tokenType;
        session.discordUser = token.profile;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (account.provider != "discord" && !user.id) {
        return;
      }

      return {
        user: {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          image: user.image,
          banner: profile.banner,
          accentColor: profile.accentColor,
        },
        accessToken: user.accessToken,
        expires: user.expires,
      };
    },

    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }

      return token;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: { params: { scope: "identify guilds" } },
      profile(profile) {
        let imageUrl = '';
        if (profile.avatar === null) {
          const defaultAvatarNumber = parseInt(profile.discriminator) % 5;
          imageUrl = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/${defaultAvatarNumber}.png`;
        } else {
          const format = profile.avatar.startsWith("a_") ? "gif" : "png";
          imageUrl = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${profile.id}/${profile.avatar}.${format}`;
        }

        return {
          id: profile.id,
          name: profile.username,
          discriminator: profile.discriminator,
          image: imageUrl,
          banner: profile.banner,
          accentColor: profile.accentColor,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.profile.id;
        session.user.banner = token.profile.banner;
        session.user.accentColor = token.profile.accentColor;
        // Add any other user properties you need
      }
      return session;
    },

    async jwt({ token, user, profile }) {
      if (user) {
        token.profile = profile;
      }
      return token;
    },

    // Keep other callbacks as is or modify them as needed
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```